# bluetooth keyboard will cause activity destroy and recreate

Tags: android, android-activity, bluetooth, keyboard

Bluetooth keyboard  will cause activity destroy and recreate
if I turn off it or far away from pad(Android)
Activity will be recreate
how can i avoid this problem

Comment: help...........................

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Pairing a Bluetooth keyboard is considered to be a configuration change:
Try adding the below to your AndroidManifest.xml

android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden"

From:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config
android:configChanges

Comment: Helped with keyboard connected via USB as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 28):

In contrast to [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25943087/680742), I found that `keyboard|keyboardHidden` was not enough. I was working with a Logitech Bluetooth keyboard ([model #JNZYR0021](http://support.logitech.com/en_us/product/8214)).

What did work was this:

```
<activity
  ...
  android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation"
/>
```

Apparently this Logitech keyboard also changes `navigation`, which is weird because [the Android docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config) say:

> The navigation type (trackball/dpad) has changed. (This should never normally happen.)

Go figure.

Comment: i added the statement which you suggested, but native key board not opening for edittext which are in that activity.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. It helped.

Comment: I spent weeks trying to find this issue. Touch when the customer fails to mention they were using a bluetooth keyboard. Thanks!

Comment: Terrific.. How did you manage to know that navigation was changed?

Comment: I also spent days trying to resolve this problem.  Adding "keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation" is what solved it for me.

Comment: Using wireless mouse causes activity to recreate. adding navigation in configChanges solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, add `keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation` is not enough, the Activity is still recreated. I tried to figure out a general way to find the  reason to the configuration change.

The first thing need to do is add all of the cause of config change in the Activity's configChanges to make sure your Activity won't be recreated under your situation. Then override your Activity's method `OnConfigurationChange()`, use `Configuration.diff()` to calculate the difference between your `newConfig` and the current one(You can get it from `getResources().getConfiguration()`). The result is an `decimal`, transfer it to be a `hexadecimal` and calculate how is combined by the constants name starts with `CONFIG_` in `ActivityInfo`.

For example, the configuration diff is 112 in decimal, and its hex is 0x70. In this case, we have `CONFIG_KEYBOARD = 0x0010;`, `CONFIG_KEYBOARD_HIDDEN = 0x0020`, `CONFIG_NAVIGATION = 0x0040`, which means these three flags are changed during this configuration change.

Answer (score 0):

For me, adding "orientation|screenSize|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation" to configChanges would still call onDestroy and onCreate of the activity. After a long research I found this article:
https://developer.samsung.com/sdp/blog/en-us/2017/12/07/samsung-dex-lifecycle-on-switching-between-mobile-and-samsung-dex-mode

Basically, if you use Lenovo's productivity mode or Samsung DeX, it would recreate the app nonetheless, so it's necessary to add all of these if you want for the app to not recreate itself when you add a physical/bluetooth keyboard.:

```
<activity android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|density">
```

Also, add this for Samsung DeX inside your AndroidManifest:

```
<meta-data 
android:name="com.samsung.android.keepalive.density" 
android:value="true" />
```